# Execution of code in else block and after if block

Tags: c++

In this code i want to know what is the difference between code executed in else and code executed after if block?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int digits(int number, int value, int times){
    int counter = times;
    counter++;
    int result = number/value;
    value=value*10;
    if (result != 0){
        digits(number,value,counter);
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    int number,no_of_digit;
    cout << "Enter the number : ";
    cin >> number;
    no_of_digit = digits(number, 10, 0);
    cout << "No of digits are : " << no_of_digit << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work properly. It give value 1.
But if i put `return counter;` in else block it works. Why so?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are ignoring the return value of digits function

```
int counter = times;
counter++;
int result = number/value;
value=value*10;
if (result != 0){
    digits(number,value,counter);
}
return counter;
```

should say

```
int counter = times;
counter++;
int result = number/value;
value=value*10;
if (result != 0){
    return digits(number,value,counter);
}
return counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code is when calling using recursion in digits function call like this

```
counter=digits(number, value , counter);
```

if you don't use the above one and keep an else the problem is the else block(return statement) will be executed only once in the call stack and the top most function call stack  will return the counter directly to your main function and will get the result correctly and this is not a good way of coding

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure by what you mean when you say "this code doesn't work."... but it looks like your `digits(int, int, int)` method will always return a 1 (with the code provided above.
ex: `digits(number, 10, 0);`

this is due to the fact of the way recursion works in your current code set up:
    ...

```
if (result != 0){
    digits(number,value,counter); //recursion happens here and returns an int value to nothing.
}
return counter;

...
```

If you changed the code to have an else block after the above if, then I imagine you had a return in the if block as well (because you would HAVE TO). so the code probably looked like this:

```
...

if (result != 0){
    return digits(number,value,counter);
}
else {
    return counter;
}

...
```

with the code have a return statement in the if and else blocks your recursion set will work because it will eventually hit the else block and return your accumulating counter (this will work because you are doing integer division and truncating the decimal value like this `int result = number/value;`. and this works because you increase the value of the `value` parameter by 10)... with that being said, this code is pretty brittle, if you used a large enough number for the `number` parameter, you would get an overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that, if you try following you might get some weird answers. Note that the `else` part is still there.

```
if (result != 0) {
    int i = digits(number, value, counter);
    cout << i;
} else {
    return counter;
}
```

Just replace your if block with following, it will always give you correct answer.

```
if (result != 0) {
    return digits(number, value, counter);
} else {
    return counter;
}
```

**Why?**

This is happening because you are not returning `int` value, which you are supposed to.

Caller of the function will read return values through some mechanism. In this specific case, return value is of type `int` and most probable way of reading return value is through a register. When you don’t include return statement, whatever garbage value that register has, will get returned.